# postgresql : search records based on array field vaule with multiple values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has an array field.

```
CREATE TABLE notifications
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('notifications_id_seq'::regclass),
    title character(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    tags text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT notifications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and `tags` field can have multiple values from

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

now I want all the records for which tags have `a` or `d` (`"a","d"`)array values.

I can use [postgresl in](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/) but this can be used to search single value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) "*Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign*"

Comment: @Sunil Garg Was any of the provided answers helpful to you ?

Comment: @Dvorog, I was busy, I will check today and if this helps then ovbio you will get the reward for this. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ANY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM notifications
WHERE 'a' = ANY(tags) OR 'b' = ANY(tags);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c047b404dc46307e4634d14ff8274f04)**

Answer (score 1):

If the values 'a' and 'b' are static (you only need to check for those 2 values in every query), then you can go with the solution that Lukasz Szozda provided.

But if the values you want to check for are dynamic and are different in multiple queries(sometimes it is {'a','b'} but sometimes it is {'b', 'f','m'})  you can create an intersection of both of the arrays and check if the intersection is empty.

For example:

If we have the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table_1(description TEXT, tags TEXT[]);
INSERT INTO test_table_1(description, tags) VALUES
  ('desc1', array['a','b','c']),
  ('desc2', array['c','d','e']);
```

If we want to get all of the rows from `test_table_1` that have one of the following tags `b`, `f`, or `m`, we could do it with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table_1 tt1
 WHERE  array_length((SELECT array
    (
        SELECT UNNEST(tt1.tags)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT UNNEST(array['b','f','m'])
    )), 1) > 0;
```

In the query above we use `array_length` to check if the intersection is empty.

Writing the query this way can also be useful if you want to add additional constraint to the number of matched tags. 
For example if you want to get all of the rows that have at least 2 tags from the group {'a','b','c'} you just need to set `array_length(...) > 1`